# Bringing P-type and N-type semiconductors together in vacuum

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Consider the case where a P-type semiconductor and an N-type semiconductor are placed in perfect vacuum. Now, the two junctions are brought together.

1. In the time immediately after they are brought in contact (say the first 1 micro seconds after they are brought in contact), the electrons from the N-side will diffuse into P-side and holes from P-side will diffuse into N-side. During this period, will I detect a current in the wire connecting the P-side to the N-side?
2. If the answer to the above question is yes, what happens if I do not have any sort of external circuit? Is the depletion region not formed?

Comment: Forming the depletion region does not need current external to the semiconductor. Electrons and holes will combine in the depletion region, and that is all that is needed.

Comment: I think I wasn't being clear. I edited the question. Since there is transfer of holes from P-side to the N-side and electrons from N to P, will I detect a current in the external wires (which connect P side to N side) during this transient period?

Comment: https://youtu.be/IcrBqCFLHIY Check this out. The depletion can form even if you don't connect the external circuit. It is just setting up a potential difference right at the depletion layer. And at the '0' state, even if you connect external circuit, I think, current's not gonna flow(assuming you are joining the ends of the semi-conductors which are away from the region of depletion layer). As explained in the video, as soon as you connect a voltage gate, you are gonna get a supply. Hope it's clear.

Comment: @JonCuster These are not comments but the answer.